# How do I associate a flag image with an iso country code on a map?

Tags: carto, infowindow

I am mapping fibre optic infrastructure in Africa using CartoDB and in the infoWindow, I am listing the operator, owner, construction, and financing organisations.  Each organisation has an ISO country code associated with it.  I would like to have a tiny (SVG?) country flag next to each organisation in the infoWindow.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think to do it is:

1. Adding another column in your data table that is a link to an external image of the country flags
2. Change the infowindow HTML template so that the flag appears where you want it

For example, something like this:

```
<div class="cartodb-popup v2">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
      <h4><img src="{{image_column}}" /> {{organization_column}}</h4>
      <p>{{other_info}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
```

When you do it this way, the HTML will be templated for the infowindow and will fill in the information in the places you require. In this case, the `img` tag will get an image url to display in your infowindow.

Infowindows use [mustache templates](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) for formatting -- that's what the double curly braces are around column names.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  There seem to be some handy resources like this one https://github.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon which has the icons in a format consistent with iso2 code + .png for the file name, which is ideal for me.  I suppose I now need to finally my map (https://afterfibre.cartodb.com/tables/af_fibrephase/map) to its own website in order to be able to host the flag icons.